# React best way of fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, server-side-rendering

Im tryng to do a little React App with Riot API which shows you your recent games etc...

I'm using React and NextJS ('m new to NextJS). I'm wondering what'd be the best way of fetching data.

I've an API developed with expressjs which works perfectly.

Now, the API has two basic endpoints:

- `/:summonerName/puuid`: this endpoint returns the puiid of a player based on his summoner name
- `/:puuid/matches`: this endpoint returns a list of matches IDs based on puiid of player
- `/matches/:matchId`: this endpoint returns the game info based on the provided match ID.

So, my first solution was fetching the puiid in the main component. Inside it, a matchList component which has the state of the list (/:puuid/matches) and then a map that array and generate a match component per element and on it fetch (/matches/:matchID). That solution worked but it was all a bit tricky because each component had to awit till the other complete the request and it will load by parts.

Now I'm using NextJS and there is Server Side Rendering which I don't know if it's a good idea for this part or no. And I'm trying to make a server side rendering and in the main component fetch the match array and the match info in server side rendering but it's not working `Error: Error serializing .matches[0] returned from getServerSideProps in "/". Reason: object ("[object Promise]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.`.Here's the code:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const puuid = 'XXXXX'
  const matchList = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/${puuid}/matches/`).then((response) => response.json());
    
  const matches = await Promise.all(
    matchList.map(async (matchId: string) => {
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/matches/${matchId}/`)
      return await res.json()
    }
  ));
    
  return { props: matches }
    
}
```

So I need help with which would be the best approach to this problem. And how would you resolve chained request as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The data fetching technique you want to use depends on your use cases. Fetching from the client side always results in a loading state, but it is faster. However, you can render from the server side without having to wait for a loading state. That is slower. The drawbacks depend on how you intend for your uses to access the data.

Also, I'm not sure why your server side code isn't working. Especially, when you say "it's not working". What isn't working? You need to give more information on that. But check the following:

1. Make sure you're calling `getServerSideProps` inside a component that is a page. That is, `getServerSideProps` should be inside a file within `/pages`
2. Try parsing your data before exporting the prop `{ props: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matches)) }`. Remember to pass the `props` to the parent component

Comment: The error is: `Error: Error serializing .matches[0] returned from getServerSideProps in "/".
Reason: object ("[object Promise]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.` Let's say It returns 10 matches so I'll have to make a 10 request to other endpoint, after that the data will not change. So I don't know if it's best practices divide it in a List component which fetchs the array and then renders 10 components and each one make an unique fetch request. Or make it in the same component

Comment: The error is because of the data you're returning from your api call. confirm that is it as json object before serialising. If the data changes only once or twice, you can just use a tool like `SWR` https://swr.vercel.app/ . That should prevent the loading screens for subsequent api calls. Also, check your code inside the getserversideprops. I see you're passing a matchid but i'm not sure from where.

Comment: Match ID come from the matchList which is an array.

Comment: oouh I just realised  `matchList.map(async (matchId: string)` this won't work the way you want it too. That whole function returns nothing. It'll be better to take the map outside of there. place it above. so you generate the unique sets of url and then loop through that array and pass to fetch api...like `uniqueLinks.map(link=>fetch(link)`

Answer (score -1):

you can use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), it is promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js. You can find a lot of videos and blogs online on how to use it. You will also find it in their npm package description.